# How to treat autocomplete suggestion as link to that post in WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, autocomplete

So I have a WordPress site with autocomplete suggestions for my search box. What I'm trying to do is to make all autocomplete suggestions as links to that exact post/page.

Also if possible, how to separate posts from pages and add HTML div for title "Pages" and div for "Posts" ?

PHP Code: (functions.php)

```
<?php
/**
 * Enqueue scripts and styles.
 *
 * @since 1.0.0
 */
 function ja_global_enqueues() {
 wp_enqueue_style(
    'jquery-auto-complete',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery- 
 autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.css',
    array(),
    '1.0.7'
 );
 wp_enqueue_script(
    'jquery-auto-complete',
    'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery- 
 autocomplete/1.0.7/jquery.auto-complete.min.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    '1.0.7',
    true
 );
 wp_enqueue_script(
    'global',
    get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/global.min.js',
    array( 'jquery' ),
    '1.0.0',
    true
 );
 wp_localize_script(
    'global',
    'global',
    array(
        'ajax' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ),
    )
 );
 }
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ja_global_enqueues' );
/**
* Live autocomplete search feature.
*
* @since 1.0.0
*/
function ja_ajax_search() {
$results = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'     => array( 'post', 'page' ),
    'post_status'   => 'publish',
    'nopaging'      => true,
    'posts_per_page'=> 100,
    's'             => stripslashes( $_POST['search'] ),
) );
$items = array();
if ( !empty( $results->posts ) ) {
    foreach ( $results->posts as $result ) {
        $items[] = $result->post_title;
    }
}
wp_send_json_success( $items );
}
add_action( 'wp_ajax_search_site',        'ja_ajax_search' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_search_site', 'ja_ajax_search' );
```

jQuery Code:

```
jQuery(function($){
var searchRequest;
$('.search-autocomplete').autoComplete({
    minChars: 2,
    source: function(term, suggest){
        try { searchRequest.abort(); } catch(e){}
        searchRequest = $.post(global.ajax, { search: term, action: 
'search_site' }, function(res) {
            suggest(res.data);
        });
    }
 });
 });
```

HTML Code inside .php file:

```
<form class="navbar-form" role="search" method="get" action="<?php echo esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ); ?>">
<div class="form-group">
    <input type="text" name="s" class="form-control search-autocomplete" placeholder="Search">
</div>
<button type="submit" class="fa fa-search"></button>
</form>
```